# How can a Simple.OData.Client read the maximum allowed page size for OData V2 APIs

Tags: odata, simple.odata.client

I am using the Simple.OData.Client library to download entities from an OData V2 API. I know how to use the skip-flag to request the next page if server side paging is enabled.

However, I could not find any way to determine if Server-Side paging has occurred. Is there any way to read this from the library?